# How to delete elements from a numpy array using indecies returned by scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point method

Tags: python, numpy, kdtree

I am trying to use Kdtree data structure to remove closest points from an array preferablly without for loops.

```
import sys

import time

import scipy.spatial

class KDTree:
    """
    Nearest neighbor search class with KDTree
    """

    def __init__(self, data):
        # store kd-tree
        self.tree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(data)

    def search(self, inp, k=1):
        """
        Search NN
        inp: input data, single frame or multi frame
        """

        if len(inp.shape) >= 2:  # multi input
            index = []
            dist = []

            for i in inp.T:
                idist, iindex = self.tree.query(i, k=k)
                index.append(iindex)
                dist.append(idist)

            return index, dist

        dist, index = self.tree.query(inp, k=k)
        return index, dist

    def search_in_distance(self, inp, r):
        """
        find points with in a distance r
        """

        index = self.tree.query_ball_point(inp, r)
        return np.asarray(index)


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
start = time.time()
fig, ar = plt.subplots()
t = 0
R = 50.0
u = R *np.cos(t)
v = R *np.sin(t)

x = np.linspace(-100,100,51)
y = np.linspace(-100,100,51)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
points =np.vstack((xx.ravel(),yy.ravel())).T
Tree = KDTree(points)
ind = Tree.search_in_distance([u, v],10.0)
ar.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],c='k',s=1)
infected = points[ind]
ar.scatter(infected[:,0],infected[:,1],c='r',s=5)

def animate(i):
    global R,t,start,points
    ar.clear()
    u = R *np.cos(t)
    v = R *np.sin(t)
    ind = Tree.search_in_distance([u, v],10.0)
    ar.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],c='k',s=1)
    infected = points[ind]
    ar.scatter(infected[:,0],infected[:,1],c='r',s=5)
    #points = np.delete(points,ind)
    t+=0.01
    end = time.time()
    if end - start != 0:
        print((end - start), end="\r")
        start = end
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

but no matter what i do i can't get np.delete to work with the indecies returned by the ball_query method. What am i missing?

I would like to make the red colored points vanish in each iteration from the points array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `points` array is a Nx2 matrix. Your `ind` indices are a list of row indices. What you need is to specify the axis along which you need deletion, ultimately this:

```
points = np.delete(points,ind,axis=0)
```

Also, once you delete indices, watch out for missing indices in your next iteration/calculations. Maybe you want to have a copy to delete points and plot and another copy for calculations that you do not delete from it.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir,but it is deleting the wrong points  -

Comment: Well, that means you did not select the correct indices. As I mentioned in my post, you created a tree that is never updated and keep deleting points from points (and not the Tree itself). Of course, it will start deleting the wrong indices, just because the indices in the Tree are not the same as indices in the points anymore. I also made a suggestion on how to fix it. On the other hand, what you specifically asked in the question is resolved by this post. Thank you